# Get meta data with path when using Dropbox in a different language

Tags: metadata, dropbox

I am using Third party SDKs (i.e. Apring-Net-Social-Dropbox).
I have a problem when I try to get metadata of path in Hebrew language. In particular, I get the following exception: `DropboxApiException - HttpStatusCode.NotFound`

Can you explain why I get this error?